# Linux x86-64 Hello World and register usage for parameters

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I found this page which has a Hello World example for x86-64 on Linux:

http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/64-bit-hello-world-in-linux-assembly-nasm/

```
; 64-bit "Hello World!" in Linux NASM

global _start            ; global entry point export for ld

section .text
_start:

    ; sys_write(stdout, message, length)

    mov    rax, 1        ; sys_write
    mov    rdi, 1        ; stdout
    mov    rsi, message    ; message address
    mov    rdx, length    ; message string length
    syscall

    ; sys_exit(return_code)

    mov    rax, 60        ; sys_exit
    mov    rdi, 0        ; return 0 (success)
    syscall

section .data
    message: db 'Hello, world!',0x0A    ; message and newline
    length:    equ    $-message        ; NASM definition pseudo-instruction
```

The Author says:

> An integer value representing the system_write call is placed in the
>   first register, followed by its arguments. When the system call and
>   its arguments are all in their proper registers, the system is called
>   and the message is displayed.

- What does he mean by "proper" registers/What would be an im"proper" register?
- What happens if I have a function with more arguments than I have registers?
- Does `rax` always point to the function call (this would always be a system call?)? Is that its only purpose?

Answer (score 3):

By "the proper registers", the author means the registers specified by the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), in the Linux Kernel Calling Conventions section. The system call number goes in `rax`, and arguments go in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8` and `r9`, in that order.

This calling convention (especially the use of `syscall`!) is only used for system calls, which can only have up to six arguments. Application functions use a different (but similar) calling convention which spills some arguments to the stack, or to other registers.

Comment: Thanks for replying- a few questions: 1) So all system calls have less than 7 arguments? 2) Does rax also perform the same "duty" for application functions? 3) Why only rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8 and r9? Aren't there a few other registers which could be used on x86-64?

Comment: @user997112 1) There are none, but if were, a temporary structure could be used. 2) No, it doesn't. 3) Any calling convention is a trade-off between convenience for a caller and a callee. With more than 6 parameters, stack is used to pass others. But this is usually rare.