# Segmentation Fault in a simple Assembly code on my architecture

Tags: assembly, x86, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In a course about C/C++ , I have the following assembly code named hello-x64.S :

```
.text
    .global _start

_start:

        movl    $len,%edx
        movl    $msg,%ecx
        movl    $1,%ebx
        movl    $4,%eax
        int     $0x80

        movl    $0,%ebx
        movl    $1,%eax
        int     $0x80

.data
msg:
        .ascii  "Bonjour le monde!\n"
        len = . - msg
```

I have executed as indicated with the lines :

```
as -o hello-x64.o hello-x64.S
ld -o hello-x64 hello-x64.o
./hello-x64
```

But in my case, I have the following error message. 
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Could someone explain to me why , please ?

Thank you

Comment: Is "your architecture" the linux in windows thing by any chance? That is 32 bit code but should accidentally work in a true linux. It does not work in the windows emulation thing or on macos.

Comment: This is missing info about what platform.  So it needs to be closed as lacking details along with the [mcve].  But since it's probably what Jester suggested, closing it as a dup.  If further details (like being on MacOS) mean it's something different, we can re-open.

Comment: I use WSL (Linux in Windows) on x86-64 pc

Comment: WSL does not support 32 bit code which this one is. Use a proper 64 bit version.

Comment: I have 3 questions : 1) do you mean I should use a true LInux 64 bits ?    2) when you read my code, How do you recognize that this is 32 bit code     3) Can I adapt this code to make it 64 bits ?

Comment: 1) if you do it will work, but it's not recommended. See the question marked as duplicate 2) `int $0x80` is the 32 bit system call 3) yes, although that would mean changing all of the instructions. Depends whether you call that adapting or not. Anyway, there are plenty of 64 bit [hello world examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19743373/547981) (although that one is nasm syntax but you get the idea).

Comment: You wrote "WSL does not support 32 bit code which this one is. Use a proper 64 bit version."  So, what do you mean precisely by "use a proper 64 bit version" ? please

Comment: I have linked you to a 64 bit version. You can also find other examples.

Comment: another question please : When you write about executing the code on a 64 bit architecture, " if you do it will work, but it's not recommended. ",  so, what is recommended ?

Comment: And a last question : does an emulator like QEMU on windows 64 bits can enable me to simulate LINUX 32 or 64 bits ?

Comment: It's recommended to write 64 bit code if you intend to create a 64 bit program. Yes, `qemu` can simulate 32 or 64 bit, and a simulated 64 bit linux has 32 bit compatibility, but for that you should create a 32 bit program (e.g. `gcc -m32` or `as --32`, `ld -melf_i386`). This only works on linux as WSL does not support 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to update my version of VirtualBox on Windows, to use Ubuntu

Comment: Will it work with VirtualBox and Ubuntu on it ? because I am reinstalling everything , based on that choice

Comment: Yes, it should work with VirtualBox and ubuntu. If you install 32 bit ubuntu it will work as-is. If you install 64 bit it will still work, but that's not recommended. In that case install the 32 bit toolchain and compile to a 32 bit program.