# Segmentation fault NASM Assembly 64-Bit

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am currently studying Computer Architecture and one core topic is assembler. For some reason the prof's example code doesn't work on my computer. I am using a 64-Bit Linux-Subsystem for Windows to assemble, compile, debug and execute the code.
Here is the example:

```
section .data

msg: db "Hello world!", 0x0a
errmsg: db "Error!", 0x0a

section .bss

buf1: resb 40
buf2: resb 20

section .text
global _start

write_msg:
mov eax, 4 ; write syscall
mov ebx, 1 ; to stdout
mov ecx, msg ; buffer to write
mov edx, 13 ; number of bytes to write
int 80h ; kernel interrupt
ret

_start:
call write_msg
mov eax, 1 ; exit syscall
mov ebx, 0 ; exit code 0
int 80h ; kernel interrupt
```

I am assembling, compiling and executing the code as follows:

```
nasm -g -f elf64 helloworld.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 -static -o helloworld helloworld.o
./helloworld
```

When doing so I simply get the error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I tried debugging it with GDB to find the cause of the error (even though this example was given to us by our professor and it works perfectly fine on a friends pc):

```
gdb helloworld

set disassembly-flavor intel

break *write_msg+1

run
```

And I also get an error message which says:

```
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 223.223 failed: No such file or directory
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x401001
```

I have googled to try to find something that explains and fixes this error but I couldnt find anything.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for setting a breakpoint? Why break at `write_msg`  and not at `_start`?

Comment: Same problem occurs when breaking at _start

Comment: That is 32 bit code, that will not work in a 64 bit WSL.

Comment: Is there a documentation where I can see the syntax differences between 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: The syntax is the same, but 64 bit uses different way to do system calls. You should be able to find [64 bit hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743373/linux-x86-64-hello-world-and-register-usage-for-parameters) easily.

Comment: Your first instruction isn't 1 byte long, so `break *write_msg+1` isn't a good place to insert a breakpoint.  IDK why it failed to even open the process's `/proc/PID/mem` file, though, once GDB started a child process (when you did `run`).  Use `starti` to stop before the first instruction in the new process without needing a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently WSL is **only** 64-bit and 32-bit code simply dose not work. Secondly, in 64-bit mode you should use 64-bit registers and `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`. If you would like to use 32-bit programs upgrade to WSL2.

Comment: If you use WSL2 (you can upgrade WSL containers to WSL2) the Linux kernels are built with IA32 emulation and do support the running of 32-bit programs, where as WSL does not. You should still build 32-bit programs as 32-bit and 64-bit programs as 64-bit as mixing 32-bit `int 0x80` with 64-bit code even in WSL2 can be problematic since 64-bit pointers can't be passed to 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls.

Comment: `syscall` isn't a drop-in replacement for `int 0x80`, you have to use different call-numbers and registers.  There's a canonical Q&A about that, [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730), so I closed this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I said that you should use 64-bit registers